# connecting to webservice Using PHP & Soap

Tags: php, xml, soap, service

ok I'm trying to connect to a webservice which utilizes the OTA XML schema 
("http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05/GetVehAvailRate")

this webservice is hosted at rentcentric.com, which is a hosted solution for taking reservations and bookings online, the system requires a username and password to connect & so far every attempt at connecting has resulted in a blank white page.

no error messages no PHP output,

Im still fairly new to using SOAP, (although I did have great success when using it on an estate agents site - which **didnt** require any authentication just a simple value to identify the company on that service)

I have read and tried nearly all the examples found on this site & others with no joy!

the request made to the service is outlined below, 
each request has a core set of arguments which are:

```
PickUpDateTime //date
ReturnDateTime //date
PickUpLocation.locationCode //string
ReturnLocation.locationCode //string
PromotionCod //string
```

the service url http://www2.rentcentric.com/Ota2007a/OTASrvc.asmx has all the methods available to us.

```
# GetVehAvailRate
# VehCancel
# VehLocSearch
# VehModify
# VehRes
```

**Request -: GetVehAvailRate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <SRVCredentials xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
      <Username>*USERNAME*</Username>
      <Password>*PASSWORD*</Password>
    </SRVCredentials>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <OTA_VehAvailRateRQ EchoToken="string" TimeStamp="dateTime" Target="Test or Production" Version="decimal" TransactionIdentifier="string" SequenceNmbr="nonNegativeInteger" TransactionStatusCode="Start or End or Rollback or InSeries or Continuation or Subsequent" PrimaryLangID="language" AltLangID="language" RetransmissionIndicator="boolean" ReqRespVersion="string" MaxResponses="positiveInteger" MaxPerVendorInd="boolean" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
      <POS>............
```

**code example:**

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://www2.rentcentric.com/Ota2007a/OTASrvc.asmx?wsdl");

    // Prepare SoapHeader parameters
    $sh_param = array(
             'Username'=>'username',
             'Password'=>'password');
    $headers = new SoapHeader('http://www2.rentcentric.com/Ota2007a/', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param);

        // Prepare Soap Client
        $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($headers));
```

Im just bangning my head against the wall trying to get something to return, 
All I need is pointed in the right direction...

Comment: Your sample code does not show you attempting to perform any actual calls to the service, or output the result. As well as the `'trace'` option mentioned by user470714, you can also enable the `'exceptions'` option so that "faults" returned by the server are thrown as Exceptions of class `SoapFault`. Obviously, you should also ensure you have your PHP [error reporting configured](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) correctly if you are see a blank output page.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

to see how to add the trace variable to your SoapClient constructor. Once you've done that you can use

- SoapClient::__getLastRequestHeaders
- SoapClient::__getLastRequest
- SoapClient::__getLastResponse
- SoapClient::__getLastResponseHeaders

As a means to, at the very least, get some feedback as to why your calls are failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using another soap implementation and see if the problem persists. I suggest you [Zend Soap](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html)